# How to reduce memory usage for Meteor?

Tags: memory, meteor, out-of-memory

I created a very simple Meteor (v1.0.1, development mode) web application, it's on a staging server so only a few users has access to it. The server is on Rackspace and have 1GB of memory.

When I returned from my weekend break, I get this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory Aborted (core dumped)
```

I restarted the application and ran `top`. I see that I only have 70MB of memory left, and the top three process are from meteor, taking up nearly 60% of the memory. The second process (15517) keeps creaping up in memory usage (9.7, when first started, to 10.6 in about an hour), and I have a feeling it might be the one that causes out-of-memory (OOM) error.

```
  PID USER   PR   NI   VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                         
15445 root   20   0 1367736 443624   2792 S 10.3 43.8   6:09.26 [dir]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.36.1rumazb++os.linux.+
15517 root   20   0  830796 107040   3172 R  3.0 10.6   1:07.75 [dir]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.36.1rumazb++os.linux.+
15468 root   20   0  813608  36348   1824 S  0.3  3.6   0:04.82 [dir]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.36.1rumazb++os.linux.+
```

I have asked, in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27596083/2317532), what these processes do, but in this question, I want to focus on **what can I do to reduce the memory usage of Meteor?** Is there a way to cap how much memory can be allocated to Meteor, to prevent this fatal error? It is a very simple application after all.

Comment: don't run meteor on your server in the development mode.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue. It can now run using 50MB RAM. Thank you.

Comment: wow, didn't realize this is the answer you were looking for

Comment: Could you post it as an answer and have it accepted then?